# What does the MOVZBL instruction do in IA-32 AT&T syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, zero-extension

What exactly does this instruction do?

```
movzbl  0x01(%eax,%ecx), %eax
```

Comment: same for movsbl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861095/what-does-movsbl-instruction-do

Comment: @Waqar: I don't think your edit was an improvement, and seems too small to be worth bumping the question for.  If you're going to add a space, I'd only add one between the two operands, not also inside the addressing mode.  It's totally normal to write AT&T addressing modes without spaces since there are already commas and the allowed things are so rigid.  So I'd have written `movzbl 1(%eax,%ecx), %eax` (that's the formatting GCC's asm output uses: https://godbolt.org/z/E4r9dP).  This might have been literal compiler output or disassembly someone copy/pasted, with that spacing.

Comment: Alright, I will keep this in mind for future edits.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

AT&T syntax splits the [`movzx` Intel instruction mnemonic](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVZX.html) into different mnemonics for different source sizes (`movzb` vs. `movzw`).  In Intel syntax, it's:

```
movzx eax, byte ptr [eax+ecx+1]
```

i.e. load a byte from memory at eax+ecx+1 and zero-extend to full register.

BTW, most GNU tools now have a switch or a config option to prefer Intel syntax.  (Such as `objdump -Mintel` or `gcc -S -masm=intel`, although the latter affects the syntax used when compiling inline-asm).  I would certainly recommend to look into it, if you don't do AT&T assembly for living.  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more docs and guides.

Comment: Understood: this will load the byte from `%eax + %ecx + 1` address and expand it to long with a leading zeros. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming I'm looking at a `movzbl` in 64-bit x86_64 code, would "zero-extend to full register" refer to %eax, or the full %rax?

Comment: @MariusGedminas you can probably use rax explicitly with movzbq but any operation on a 32-bit register zeroes out the top 32 bits, so in effect movzbl to eax  will extend to rax.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Thank you!  (I was looking at a disassembly output of a function that somehow managed a 32-bit signed overflow while mixing 64-bit unsigned and double arithmetic.  movzbl was not the culprit.)

Answer (score 31):

**Minimal example**

```
mov $0x01234567, %eax
mov $1, %bl
movzbl %bl, %eax
/* %eax == 0000 0001 */

mov $0x01234567, %eax
mov $-1, %bl
movzbl %bl, %eax
/* %eax == 0000 00FF */
```

[Runanble GitHub upstream with assertions](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-assembly-cheat/blob/8e1407a2cfd3326995d45a93a94c185a9f799c5d/movzx.asm).

The mnemonic is:

- MOV
- Zero extend
- Byte (8-bit)
- to Long (32-bit)

There are also versions for other sizes:

- `movzbw`: Byte (8-bit) to Word (16-bit)
- `movzwl`: Word (16-bit) to Long (32-bit)

Like most GAS instructions, you can omit the last size character when dealing with registers:

```
movzb %bl, %eax
```

but I cannot understand why we can't omit the before last letter, e.g. the following fails:

```
movz %bl, %eax
```

Why not just deduce it from the size of the operands when they are registers as for `mov` and Intel syntax?

And if you use registers of the wrong size, it fails to compile e.g.:

```
movzb %ax, %eax
```

Comment: If you [look at the opcodes](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVZX.html), the "operand size" controls the size of the destination but there are different opcodes for different sizes of source.  So it makes sense for gas to treat `movzb` as a separate instruction from `movzw`.  (For sign-extension, AMD even added a new Intel-syntax mnemonic for `movsxd r64, r/m32` instead of further overloading `movsx`.  IDK why.)