# need help understanding the movzbl call in this function

Tags: c, assembly, x86

So I'm trying to write some C code by looking at the assembly here:

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
movl    12(%ebp), %eax
addl    8(%ebp), %eax
movzbl  (%eax), %eax
movsbl  %al,%eax
popl    %ebp
ret
```

I see that I have two variables, and they are being added together, then I'm getting lost when looking when the function starts calling movzbl and movesbl.  What's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the MOVZBL instruction do in IA-32 AT&T syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317922/what-does-the-movzbl-instruction-do-in-ia-32-att-syntax)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A corresponding C function would be something like

```
char fn(char * string, int index)
{
    return string[index];
}
```

Specifically, the `movzbl` instruction fetches the byte stored at the sum of the two parameters, zero pads it, and stores it into `eax`. The `movsbl` instruction takes the lowest byte of eax, sign extends it, and stores the result back in eax.

Comment: Hrm, ok I'm still a bit confused, so if I'm dealing with strings and characters, what's the addl call doing then?  I had previously thought that I was adding two integers together. Does that just combine the string and the index?

Comment: In assembler, you generally don't know this until you see how the result is used. Here, you see that there is an indirect load from the result, so it must have been a pointer, so one of the two parameter must have been a pointer, and the other an integer of the same size (it's impossible to tell from this code snippet which was which).

Comment: Ah ok, so what it's trying to do is something like what you wrote, it's attempting to get a specific character from some string?

Comment: Technically, it was not necessarily a character, all we can know is that it was a signed 8 bit quantity, but on many systems, a character would match that profile.

Comment: Ah I see.  So it could be anything possibly?