# movzbl and movsbl next to each other

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit

IA-32 assembly:

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
movl    12(%ebp), %eax
addl    8(%ebp), %eax
movzbl  (%eax), %eax    # <-
movsbl  %al,%eax        # <-
popl    %ebp
ret
```

I highlighted which lines are confusing for me. I kind of understand what movzbl and movsbl do separately, but what purpose do they serve by being side by side?

Why not just use `movl`. If we wanted to use sign extend, why don't we just use `movsbl` from the start, or aren't we losing data when we are extending `al` register, which is only only byte (when size of data is more than 1 byte)?

EDIT: i found this Q&A, but I still could not get it: [need help understanding the movzbl call in this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253314/need-help-understanding-the-movzbl-call-in-this-function)

EDIT2: I realized that I'm dealing with characters, so that clears some things up.

Comment: Probably reading from a `signed char` array but the function returns a `signed int`. The compiler preferred to overwrite the whole `eax` when reading from the array instead of writing only `al` to prevent stalls on old/side architectures.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I'm dealing with chars and that's why 1-bit register is satisfactory. So, I understand that part.

Comment: Everything else is still confusing for me. Could it be that it is some weird compiler stuff that we are dealing with?

Comment: If you compile with optimization disabled, the compiler sometimes makes extra-inefficient asm...  Go figure.  (And yes, in the mainstream x86 calling conventions, `char` is signed.)