# MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instruction-set

Here's the instruction which copies (converts) unsigned registers: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVZX.html

Basically the instruction has 8->16, 8->32, 8->64, 16->32 and 16->64.

Where's the 32->64 conversion?  Do I have to use the signed version for that?
If so how do you use the full 64 bits for an unsigned integer?

Comment: That is because you never need it, a 32-bit register load already resets the upper 32-bits to 0.  Backgrounder [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25456097/17034).  Note that this isn't the same case for MOVSX, it does have the dedicated MOVSXD

Comment: Hans is correct. In 64-bit code, when the destination operand is a 32-bit register the CPU automatically zero extends the result through the upper 32-bits of the 64-bit register. If you have a value in the lower 32 bits of a 64-bit register and want to make sure the upper 32-bits are set to zero you can use a regular `mov` to do that. `mov eax, eax` for example would set the upper 32-bits of RAX to zero.

Comment: Fun fact: due to some encoding quirks, `movsxd eax,eax` is a valid instruction.

Comment: You don't need one because [most 32-bit instructions zero to top bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137/995714)

Comment: @phuclv : I'd say there are places where you may need to zero extend a 32-bit register and put it in a zero extended destination. Off the top of my head the 64-bit Linux ABI doesn't guarantee that the upper 32-bits of a register used as a parameter will be zero. if you pass a uint32_t as a parameter to a function then add an uint64_t to it there will likely be an extra mov instruction to ensure the upper 32-bits are zeroed.

Comment: @phuclv: Hans already said that.  And it's not just most, it's *all* instructions that write 32-bit registers.  Anyway, it's still an interesting ISA-design (and/or assembler pseudo-instruction) question why there isn't a form of `movzx` that does 32->64.  See my answer.

Answer (score 21):

### Short answer

**Use `mov eax, edi` to zero-extend EDI into RAX** if you can't already guarantee that the high bits of RDI are all zero.  See: [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)

Prefer using different source/destination registers, because [mov-elimination fails for `mov eax,eax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all) on both Intel and AMD CPUs. When moving to a different register you incur zero latency with no execution unit needed.  (gcc apparently doesn't know this and usually zero-extends in place.)  Don't spend extra instructions to make that happen, though.

---

### Long answer

### Machine-code reason why there's no encoding for movzx with a 32-bit source

**summary: Every different source width for movzx and movsx needs a different opcode**.  The destination width is controlled by prefixes.  Since `mov` can do the job, a new opcode for `movzx dst, r/m32` would be redundant.

When designing AMD64 assembler syntax, AMD chose not to make `movzx rax, edx` work as a pseudo-instruction for `mov eax, edx`.  This is probably a good thing, because knowing that writing a 32-bit register zeros the upper bytes is very important to writing efficient code for x86-64.

---

AMD64 did need a new opcode for *sign* extension with a 32-bit source operand.  They named the mnemonic `movsxd` for some reason, instead of making it a 3rd opcode for the `movsx` mnemonic.  Intel documents them all together in [one ISA ref manual entry](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOVSX_MOVSXD).  They repurposed the 1-byte opcode that was `ARPL` in 32-bit mode, so `movsxd` is actually 1 byte shorter than `movsx` from 8 or 16-bit sources (assuming you still need a REX prefix to extend to 64-bit).

Different destination sizes use the same opcode with different operand size<sup>1</sup>.  (`66` or `REX.W` prefix for 16-bit or 64-bit instead of the default 32 bit.)  e.g. `movsx eax, bl` and `movsx rax, bl` differ only in the REX prefix; same opcode.  (`movsx ax, bl` is also the same, but with a 66 prefix to make the operand-size 16 bit.)

Before AMD64, there was no need for an opcode that reads a 32-bit source, because the maximum destination width was 32 bits, and "sign-extension" to the same size is just a copy.  Notice that [`movsxd eax, eax` is legal but not recommended](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOVSX_MOVSXD).  You can even encode it with a `66` prefix to read a 32-bit source and write a 16-bit destination<sup>2</sup>.

> The use of MOVSXD without REX.W in 64-bit mode is discouraged. Regular MOV should be used instead of using MOVSXD without REX.W.

32->64 bit sign extension can be done with `cdq` to sign-extend EAX into EDX:EAX (e.g. before 32-bit `idiv`).  This was the only way before x86-64 (other than of course copying and using an arithmetic right shift do broadcast the sign bit).

---

**But AMD64 already zero-extends from 32 to 64 for free with any instruction that writes a 32-bit register**.  [This avoids false dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6) for out-of-order execution, which is why AMD broke with the 8086 / 386 tradition of leaving upper bytes untouched when writing a partial register.  ([Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers))

**Since each source width needs a different opcode, no prefixes can make either of the two `movzx` opcodes read a 32-bit source**.

---

You do sometimes need to spend an instruction to zero-extend something.  It's common in compiler output for small functions, because the x86-64 SysV and Windows x64 calling conventions allow high garbage in args and return values.

As usual, **ask a compiler if you want to know how to do something in asm**, especially when you don't see instructions you're looking for.  I've omitted the `ret` at the end of each function.

**[Source + asm from the Godbolt compiler explorer, for the System V calling convention (args in RDI, RSI, RDX, ...)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoIL4WBAHQIN2DgAYAguYsiFBAGwAWAPoFVAL0wAPAhFv7ZLldVJgBKdQB2HlViTAIxFhCNaI4IgBFrfwcXN28CYiZkAmcGVAB3PzsnYLDI6Nj44kSmdS57VTMvADEe3p7kyIzLO1URQUxnJkFnBSwvCBGAKgAHUlGWQTxgFkx0EPDU%2BriE1WWOAFYeJguM2RT060yqnI88ktQmdEqAoLcVg6iMWOTVUKwGqSGVksWWqbk8Pkm6HQzlighEDF8Ig2Wx2eyYayxm22u1UACNQtY6kDGs1%2BKTwQ9oc9gvDigBbdEozBojF%2BbHEvEE/m4skUyxUhonJiLel3QaPJn6WGvBGfdDVVHozHMtz40Y60WUw7Uk7fAiBVyhCDXXjkhmQhUWAD0TtUABUEHhBKoCJgGAxvWMQqTRG4ALIASQACgBlJxgKTe5BMf0KYCqNAsABumH0eFQLEpMJerMR6Atmt5xZqBINdvFxslILNFoIoRtPBbv1CsvuDssLtUgn9qgLqgUyxEBG9pVQAGsZ3g55gQqo2V7xntUMsCHh1%2B4mLux2PI7GnCBrIPVOg1SJVK65m4SEOR6SAJ4dIcIUQMPZlEhzkWditj6xBYsmvozCwk7Tmayp6tWbj1hYErAokXaWh2GFtr2gxSKEjDSOcUikCw0hmCRqDSJo/D8EOojiCuci0CRBDkfhBFziAsj2AYACcjjnGYsi0BEtBcI4ESyOcESEVIjgkWRUgUaQVFSCRgggGYpBscp%2BGkHAsAwFAxkQEgaBssseAMJgZAUBAFlWTZxAgMAAAc9AAGbWb6xCaRApLsaQpIKEwxBvtILGkBZbK5gQADyLAMBFemkFgbKsMANlBfgsRFHgOaaal3iYMgU6SFIUV2H6QX5HukX6cwbAoLRvCMHgpKaZABHbkeGzSAAtPFsgaQxEh0ARDBEYpQVqV4bn2ANTiqMAyDIKobkGLQqgQLghDPsxayaKglnWbZrQieENG8PwrHsaEBEIJgny2ZQnEgEJBjnG5fFcFw5zfb9/3fecckKaQbIgIJBhuY4om0PYfH2LDEQROc0mkbN0gaVpOn3QZpnmSdTm2eQlCOWdLlKJl9hmNp3kYrZ/mBalIUsGFKVRTFcWJclOWYBlbDZaluWlbuhVBSVZW%2Bg15D6DVqV1ZDlWNZlLU3W1DAdV1EA9Tu%2Bb9VIQ0jUIY2SLQk3TZjqVzQtS2OBmTXprxZgGGYO17UQxAXfQqjHadzkXVwV2tTwd16Q9pBPS9Lm66QXGOHxBhw2YqOOCnadw6DU3ySRkO0HT1sqWpOPabpFGRznXB5x9sjJ1wZjnFwImyG5bmyLIReUdjeMRwT8CGYgKDE5TZMOSPzkgOuyyCOcTikAzvnM0FbMc7L3P6LzKUqelmXCzveB5eL3KS14pXlbL1U5ypSsNZNaucBrAha518B631RXG6NYjjRbcnEV3VS0hTxxgdqtda5xk4e3wF7H2R0J7nTkLIEOT9w4V3ekJMGNdziOC2t9Lg7dhK0CbhJewgCS5CFxuXfSg8zLDwDqTeyFNJ7UzYLTemPkmaUBZipVe4V14nVipvJK28SK7yFhVA%2BR8Con2KmfaWFUqry2vqxYg9UVb32ao/PgmttZv1UvrAsn9hqqAGgQMKwA4hrjwDPZaA1PInUIPYgosUBrLFQNVb2piMriGMLINI09BBOGIPYb%2BjEJr/xmjbaQ81FrLVYc7N2btoH7W9odP2CC0nN0cCgnRYde7oKjs9LAscMHaRzuDJSxce6aTLvdS2Uhq4QyhrxGSAkIjI3sLQBGskqnd3UgUji8cQD2Dro3ROyMCFozaI4TuOcTZ9KAQM6hldpBNMWRQlZBEcx%2BQNlDIAA%3D%3D%3D)**:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t zext(uint32_t a) { return a; }
uint64_t extract_low(uint64_t a) { return a & 0xFFFFFFFF; }
    # both compile to
    mov     eax, edi

int use_as_index(int *p, unsigned a) { return p[a]; }
   # gcc
    mov     esi, esi         # missed optimization: mov same,same can't be eliminated on Intel
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+rsi*4]

   # clang
    mov     eax, esi         # with signed int a, we'd get movsxd
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 4*rax]


uint64_t zext_load(uint32_t *p) { return *p; }
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]

uint64_t zext_add_result(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a+b; }
    lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
```

The default address-size is 64 in x86-64.  High garbage doesn't affect the low bits of addition, so this saves a byte vs. `lea eax, [edi+esi]` which needs a 67 address-size prefix but gives identical results for every input.  Of course, `add edi, esi` would produce a zero-extended result in RDI.

```
uint64_t zext_mul_result(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a*b; }
   # gcc8.1
    mov     eax, edi
    imul    eax, esi

   # clang6.0
    imul    edi, esi
    mov     rax, rdi    # silly: mov eax,edi would save a byte here
```

Intel recommends destroying the result of a `mov` right away when you have the choice, freeing the microarchitectural resources that `mov`-elimination takes up and [increasing the success-rate of `mov`-elimination (which isn't 100% on Sandybridge-family, unlike AMD Ryzen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all).  GCC's choice of `mov` / `imul` is best.

Also, on CPUs without mov-elimination, the `mov` before imul might not be on the critical path if it's the *other* input that's not ready yet (i.e. if the critical path goes through the input that doesn't get `mov`ed).  But `mov` after `imul` depends on both inputs so it's always on the critical path.

Of course, when these functions inline, the compiler will usually know the full state of registers, unless they come from function return values.  And also it doesn't need to produce the result in a specific register (RAX return value).  But if your source is sloppy with mixing `unsigned` with `size_t` or `uint64_t`, the compiler might be forced to emit instructions to truncate 64-bit values.   (Looking at compiler asm output is a good way to catch that and figure out how to tweak the source to let the compiler save instructions.)

---

**Footnote 1**:  Fun fact: AT&T syntax (which uses different mnemonics like `movswl` (sign-extend word->long (dword) or `movzbl`) can infer the destination size from the register like `movzb %al, %ecx`, but [won't assemble `movz %al, %ecx` even though there's no ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317922/what-does-the-movzbl-instruction-do-in-ia-32-att-syntax).  So it treats `movzb` as its own mnemonic, with the usual operand-size suffix which can be inferred or explicit.  This means each different opcode has its own mnemonic in AT&T syntax.

See also [assembly cltq and movslq difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743476/assembly-cltq-and-movslq-difference) for a history lesson on redundancy between CDQE for EAX->RAX and MOVSXD for any registers.  See [What does cltq do in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555094/what-does-cltq-do-in-assembly/45386217#45386217) or [the GAS docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html) for the AT&T vs. Intel menmonics for zero/sign-extension.

**Footnote 2: Silly computer tricks with `movsxd ax, [rsi]`**:

Assemblers refuse to assemble `movsxd eax, eax` or `movsxd ax, eax`, but it is possible to manually encode it.  `ndisasm` doesn't even disassemble it (just `db 0x63`), but GNU `objdump` does.  Actual CPUs decode it, too.  I tried on Skylake just to make sure:

```
 ; NASM source                           ; register value after stepi in GDB
mov     rdx, 0x8081828384858687
movsxd  rax, edx                         ; RAX = 0xffffffff84858687
db 0x63, 0xc2        ;movsxd  eax, edx   ; RAX = 0x0000000084858687
xor     eax,eax                          ; RAX = 0
db 0x66, 0x63, 0xc2  ;movsxd  ax, edx    ; RAX = 0x0000000000008687
```

So how does the CPU handle it internally?  Does it *actually* read 32 bits and then truncate to the operand-size?  **It turns out Intel's ISA reference manual documents the 16-bit form as [`63 /r` `MOVSXD r16, r/m16`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html), so `movsxd ax, [unmapped_page - 2]` does not fault.**  (But it incorrectly documents the non-REX forms as valid in compat / legacy mode; actually `0x63` decodes as ARPL there.  This is not the first bug in Intel's manuals.)

This makes perfect sense: the hardware can simply decode it to the same uop as `mov r16, r/m16` or `mov r32, r/m32` when there's no REX.W prefix.  Or not! 
 **Skylake's `movsxd eax,edx` (but not `movsxd rax, edx`) has an output dependency on the destination register, like it's merging into the destination!**  A loop with `times 4` `db 0x63, 0xc2   ; movsx eax, edx` runs at 4 clocks per iteration (1 per `movsxd`, so 1 cycle latency).  The uops are fairly evenly distributed to all 4 integer ALU execution ports.  A loop with `movsxd eax,edx` / `movsxd ebx,edx` / 2 other destinations runs at ~1.4 clocks per iteration (just slightly worse than the 1.25 clocks per iteration front-end bottleneck if you use plain 4x `mov eax, edx` or 4x `movsxd rax, edx`).  Timed with `perf` on Linux on i7-6700k.

We know that `movsxd eax, edx` does zero the upper bits of RAX, so it's not actually using any bits from the destination register it's waiting for, but presumably treating 16 and 32-bit similarly internally simplifies decoding, and simplifies handling of this corner case encoding that nobody should ever use.  The 16-bit form always has to actually merge into the destination, so it does have a true dependency on the output reg.  (Skylake doesn't rename 16-bit regs separately from full registers.)

GNU binutils is disassembling it incorrectly: gdb and objdump show the source operand as 32 bits, like

```
  4000c8:       66 63 c2                movsxd ax,edx
  4000cb:       66 63 06                movsxd ax,DWORD PTR [rsi]
```

when it should be

```
  4000c8:       66 63 c2                movsxd ax,dx
  4000cb:       66 63 06                movsxd ax,WORD PTR [rsi]
```

In AT&T syntax, objdump amusingly still uses `movslq`.  So I guess it treats that as a whole mnemonic, not as a `movsl` instruction with a `q` operand-size.  Or that's just the result of nobody caring about that special case that gas won't assemble anyway (it rejects `movsll`, and checks register widths for `movslq`).

Before checking the manual, I actually tested on Skylake with NASM to see if a load would fault or not.  It of course does not:

```
section .bss
    align 4096
    resb 4096
unmapped_page: 
 ; When built into a static executable, this page is followed by an unmapped page on my system,
 ; so I didn't have to do anything more complicated like call mmap

 ...
_start:
    lea     rsi, [unmapped_page-2]
    db 0x66, 0x63, 0x06  ;movsxd  ax, [rsi].  Runs without faulting on Skylake!  Hardware only does a 2-byte load

    o16 movsxd  rax, dword [rsi]  ; REX.W prefix takes precedence over o16 (0x66 prefix); this faults
    mov      eax, [rsi]            ; definitely faults if [rsi+2] isn't readable
```

**Note that `movsx al, ax` isn't possible: byte operand-size needs a separate opcode**.  Prefixes only select between 32 (default), 16-bit (0x66) and in long mode 64-bit (REX.W).  `movs/zx ax, word [mem]` has been possible since 386, but reading a source wider than the destination is a corner case that's new in x86-64, and only for sign-extension.  (And it turns out that the 16-bit destination encoding actually only reads a 16-bit source.)

---

## Other ISA-design possibilities that AMD chose not to do:

**BTW, AMD *could have* (but didn't) design AMD64 to always sign-extend instead of always zero-extend on 32-bit register writes**.  It would have been less convenient for software in most cases, and probably also take a few extra transistors, but it would still avoid false dependencies on the old value that was sitting around in a register.  It might add an extra gate delay somewhere because the upper bits of the result depend on the low bits, unlike zero-extension where they only depend on the fact that it's a 32-bit operation.  (But that's probably unimportant.)

*If* AMD had designed it that way, they'd have needed a `movzxd` *instead* of `movsxd`.  I think the major downside to this design would be needing extra instructions when packing bitfields into a wider register.  Free zero extension is handy for `shl rax,32` / `or rax, rdx` after a `rdtsc` that writes `edx` and `eax`, for example.  If it was sign-extension, you'd need an instruction to zero the upper bytes of `rdx` before the `or`.

---

**Other ISAs have made different choices: MIPS III (in ~1995) extended the architecture to 64 bits without introducing a new mode**.  Very unlike x86, there was enough opcode space left unused in the fixed-width 32-bit instruction word format.

MIPS started out as a 32-bit architecture, and never had any legacy partial-register stuff the way 32-bit x86 did from its 16-bit 8086 heritage, and from 8086's full support of 8-bit operand-size with AX = AH:AL partial regs and so on [for easy porting of 8080 source code](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/why-are-first-four-x86-gprs-named-in-such-unintuitive-order).

**MIPS 32-bit arithmetic instructions like `addu` on 64-bit CPUs require their inputs to be correctly sign-extended, and produce sign-extended outputs.**  (Everything *just works* when running legacy 32-bit code unaware of the wider registers, because shifts are special.)

> `ADDU rd, rs, rt` ([from the MIPS III manual, page A-31](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15740-f97/public/doc/mips-isa.pdf#page=43))
>
> Restrictions:
>   On 64-bit processors, if either GPR rt or GPR rs do not contain sign-extended 32-bit values (bits 63..31 equal), then the result of the operation is undefined.
>
> Operation:
>
> ```
>   if (NotWordValue(GPR[rs]) or NotWordValue(GPR[rt])) then UndefinedResult() endif
>   temp ←GPR[rs] + GPR[rt]
>   GPR[rd]← sign_extend(temp31..0)
> ```

(Note that U for unsigned in `addu` is really a misnomer, as the manual points out.  You use it for signed arithmetic too unless you actually want `add` to trap on signed overflow.)

There's a `DADDU` instruction for double-word ADDU, which does what you'd expect.  Similarly DDIV/DMULT/DSUBU, and DSLL and other shifts.

Bitwise operations stay the same: the existing AND opcode becomes a 64-bit AND; no need for a 64-bit AND but also no free sign-extending of 32-bit AND results.

MIPS 32-bit shifts are special (SLL is a 32-bit shift.  DSLL is a separate instruction).

> SLL  Shift Word Left Logical
>
> Operation:
>
> ```
> s ← sa
> temp ← GPR[rt] (31-s)..0 || 0 s
> GPR[rd]← sign_extend(temp)
> ```
>
> Programming Notes:
>   Unlike nearly all other word operations the input operand does not
>   have to be a properly sign-extended word value to produce a valid
>   sign-extended 32-bit result. The result word is always sign extended
>   into a 64-bit destination register; **this instruction with a zero shift
>   amount truncates a 64-bit value to 32 bits and sign extends it.**

I think SPARC64 and PowerPC64 are similar to MIPS64 in maintaining sign-extension of narrow results.  [Code-gen for `(a & 0x80000000) +- 12315` for `int a`](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMAdAEwAOAJzCALAFYADIIDsohaPIArHuXat6oVAFJ%2BAIT37yAZ3QBXUqi4ByAowDUddBHtEHrAJQOdsw1IBBB2CHUmwiS3oHCFYffgA2BykAD0EpdIypbyMHbn4AZm4JHXz/AN8AER1A6oC3BwAjVlJXRy8fP1qQ0PDI6Ni9RJS0zPTvAFpcgqKSssqbT3UQGwkbcnplqTX0ZYBhIxyzS2s4wrWiTYXFgGsQfKleMUFufLF%2BUVl%2BT8EJMSWbMRrDY2LbkHY2NYmEBScgXEELchwWAoDAAWwADgROBQqBA0ZjsSBgIJ%2BOQaFiiNhSFCIA1LuQGvZmgBPZbcNZo1HYRgAeXo7FZ8PIOFRmmAnHphDCqCIBAAbtgoULsMlsKhzJS2Ws3Nh2PT2AQGqQWbssLZ2bDSARUVrFnRGCwOFw%2BEJRJIZPJFEoNFo0AcDOpDVDIIt0OjZQwleNkqgHOMAOocdhx%2BMqojGuM8/JxkxETAlCrAejmbjcOOiqxIAsma7MjTXbDl9gAL1QjjjNAA7sb0XLIRYrM7FnqVkD6eDUvFxvExA5gKhY4IBNF8MQyKduOQHKaMViqRvvPsDEZzpdPDcQAVePFCqIpMJ%2BPwxGIpLJuIJ/oDyDbuOl1uPlkhaFYTPRFEAgFF0F3bFKGofE91IEBUQIdETAkGcyQpKkaTpIVGXoFktXITluSIPkBUlbBRS0CUhSlNVZQVJVQRVNUNXNbVGF1fVDWNUhmVNHAiPTa1bTJBhmDYCUXREcRpDkL1vTFP1jwDA0GmDCBQ3DAhI2WBMkxTNMM3GLMczzAsi3Mf19FLYJxi7Hs%2B1MAdrB4YdllWf8hXBABZABJAAFJgZznBcHAkR4V0IEhSA3LcdwJfc9HyfhDxs094XPchbifXh0nyEl30EV58ledDPzHHzANMYC4S2RYkWQNAoKSnE4NahCQHRdFUBnThUB9YBMPYSlqWoXDQXwwibAtEjeX5QVQRFMVaOWghpUYxV6VY9VNVmzjKRHUF1L4gSzWEq0bQOu0JMdaSBFk90FMU9RlN0VTjHUzTtIjegoxjFNDITYzYlM7MO27Vhe37Y4h3%2BLzgVBcF0XQTsqX6xtBrFaJ03Mehrm8CBV1i%2BLt067FTnydLPsyhqL34PhBBJQRn24YR4h%2Bd4SUq7zkZqqEYXqq5/n4NYbQkfheHZqR4lkeR5ElophD57YauFxrwPAyDoKpWC8Qpqk0CG2Q/3JUbsIm%2Blpv4oj5rIxbKOo8VbHWzb5W25VVT2jjKC4461lOk0LoOy1RJu8SHSk51HrdeTPS9N7fQ%2Bww1KDeBft0/79MTdhkxB5J0zBsyHKg4gHONLlxlRnU4vGIhmmAcIHBMdFmj62dIac2HB3chGqv5mxJ2nWdsa0BxZHy/LorXOKUs3cndbngoxBp1P9DpkWkGwVgcEQrScpAaReZtMRJ7SYRUv4KRr7P1nSSRtWIVqoXQKaiCWqX/X4MJZpURnYk18RpjRwtbJkttQ723IktNYK0aKu1gRtBiHtmJrF2uxIiOoA6BiNMHISocRLXXZLdKOToeCxzkh6RSKshoqXXjgn6YIdJ6RsAZPORlC4mRLnQZCRAK6sCrjXLiddHLQ2ckcXu3APKjlVmCZYAQABKvlQrzkXMuYmMV1zzwSobZe%2BQJBrxPCBLKixt67yNgfW4x8RxfkfnI5%2BgtjH01FuLEAZ9eAXyvjfKQd83iyPBJvbKI58gDyfoExYCpqRZzcUAA%3D%3D%3D) (with `-fwrapv` so compilers can't assume that `a` is non-negative because of signed-overflow UB) shows clang for PowerPC64 maintaining or redoing sign extension, and clang `-target sparc64` ANDing then ORing to ensure that only the right bits in the low 32 are set, again maintaining sign-extension.  Changing the return type or arg type to `long` or adding `L` suffixes on the AND mask constant results in code differences for MIPS64 and PowerPC64 and sometimes SPARC64; maybe only MIPS64 actually faults on 32-bit instructions with inputs that aren't correctly sign-extended, while on others it's just a software calling-convention requirement.

But AArch64 takes an approach more like x86-64, with `w0..31` registers being the low half of `x0..31`, and instructions available in two operand-sizes.

#### This whole section about MIPS has nothing to do with x86-64, but it's an interesting comparison to look at the different (better IMO) design decision made by AMD64.

I included MIPS64 compiler output in the Godbolt link above, for those sample functions.  (And a few others that tell us more about the calling convention, and what compilers.)  It often needs `dext` to zero-extend from 32 to 64 bit; but that instruction wasn't added until mips64r2.  With `-march=mips3`, `return p[a]` for unsigned `a` has to use two doubleword shifts (left then right by 32 bits) to zero extend!  It also needs an extra instruction to zero-extend add results, i.e. to implement casting from unsigned to `uint64_t`.

So I think we can be glad that x86-64 was designed with free zero-extension instead of only providing 64-bit operand size for some things.  (Like I said, x86's heritage is very different; it already had variable operand sizes for the same opcode using prefixes.)  Of course, better bitfield instructions would be nice.  Some other ISAs, like ARM and PowerPC put x86 to shame for efficient bit-field insert / extract.

Comment: I'm just going to assume that whoever downvoted this answer doesn't like CPU architecture / design and missed the very first paragraph where I directly answered the question.  Do I need a bigger font for that part of the answer to set it apart from the details of how movzx/movsx machine encodings work?

Comment: Wow, this is pure gold. Thanks Peter.

Comment: @Johan: thanks for the edit, nice idea to mark the end of "use this code" part of the answer.

Comment: Do `movsxd ax, dx` actually do a zero extend `rax=dx` on every platform?

Comment: @l4m2: That's not encodeable; `movsxd` implies a dword source.  Did you mean `movsxd ax, edx`?  (i.e. with a `66` operand-size prefix).  That only writes AX, not EAX, so no, it doesn't zero-extend.  (NASM and YASM won't assemble it either way, because it's useless, but you can manually encode it.  Or use GAS).  AFAIK its behaviour should be well-defined on all CPUs, no reason to think any would ignore the operand-size prefix's effect on the size of destination it writes.

Comment: `db 0x66, 0x63, 0xc2  ;movsxd  ax, edx    ; RAX = 0x0000000000008687` isn't what sign extend behave. I wrote `movsxd ax,dx` just because document claim it `MOVSXD r16, r/m16`

Comment: Did you try `mov rax, -1` before that to make sure you'd be able to tell that it's leaving the upper bytes unmodified, like normal for writing a 16-bit register?  On my Skylake CPU, the final RAX is `0xffffffffffff0000` after single-stepping.  (And yes, that's the same machine code GAS uses if you write `movsxd ax, edx`). And yeah fair enough, I'd forgotten how Intel documented it as `movsxd r16, r/m16` https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd

Comment: ok my bad didn't write `rax` garbage value