# can we move content from smaller register to larger register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instructions, instruction-set

For example, can we do:

```
movl %eax,%rdx    // l means 32 bits while rdx is 64 biregister
```

so if we move 32 bits content of `%eax` to `%rdx`, then only the low order 32 bits of `%rdx` get updated?

Comment: related: [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) / [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51387571)

Comment: Your question has some different interpretations. Are you looking to preserve the upper bits after a mov from a smaller register to a larger one, or are you asking what happens to the upper bits after a move from a smaller to larger register? What is the behaviour you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to write to only the low 32 bits of a 64 bit GPR, but it could be emulated by clearing the low 32 bits and bitwise OR-ing the value into it:

```
shr rdx, 32
shl rdx, 32
or rdx, rax  ; assumes top 32 bits of rax are zero
```

Or using a double precision shift and rotate:

```
shrd rdx, rax, 32
ror rdx, 32
```

Unfortunately this has a higher latency than the first version on most processors (except maybe Core2 and its direct ancestors), because
(this form of) the double precision shift commonly takes 3 cycles. For typical Intel processors it has a potential benefit in some situations because it takes fewer µops overall, but on AMD Zen and Intel Atom the `shrd` takes a handful of µops. So in general the first version should be preferred, but in specific cases there may be a reason to use the second version.

It's also possible with two overlapping stores and a load (this is slow, for example 16 cycles on Haswell due to store-forwarding fail, and even without hitting such a bad microarchitectural edge case it would not have beaten the register-only solutions):

```
mov [rsp], rdx
mov [rsp], eax
mov rdx, [rsp]
```

Answer (score 1):

`movl %eax,%rdx` (equivalent to `mov %eax,%rdx`) is not a valid instruction. The valid combinations for `MOV` can be found in the [Instruction Set Architecture reference](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov).

There are a couple of instructions that can move from smaller registers to larger registers. You can use [`MOVZX`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx) for zero extension (upper bits set to 0), or [`MOVSX`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd) sign extension where the top most bit of the source register is copied into all the higher bits of the destination register. In 64-bit long mode if the destination of any instruction (including [`MOV`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov)) is a 32-bit register then the upper 32-bits of the corresponding 64-bit register are set to 0 automatically by the processor.

These examples represent valid moves available that go from smaller registers to larger registers:

```
movzx %al, %dx     # move 8-bit register to 16-bit register. Upper 8 bits of DX set to 0
movzx %al, %edx    # move 8-bit register to 32-bit register. Upper 24 bits of EDX set to 0
                   #     Upper 32 bits of RDX also set to zero because EDX is 32-bit dest
movzx %al, %rdx    # move 8-bit register to 64-bit register. Upper 56 bits of RDX set to 0

movzx %ax, %edx    # move 16-bit register to 32-bit register.Upper 16 bits of EDX set to 0
                   #     Upper 32 bits of RDX also set to zero because EDX is 32-bit dest

#movzx %eax, %rdx  # This instruction doesn't exist. Use mov %eax, %edx

movsx %al, %dx     # Sign extend 8-bit register to 16-bit register
movsx %al, %edx    # Sign extend 8-bit register to 32-bit register
                   #     Upper 32 bits of RDX set to ZERO because EDX is 32-bit dest
movsx %al, %rdx    # Sign extend 8-bit register to 64-bit register

movsx %ax, %edx    # Sign extend 16-bit register to 32-bit register
                   #     Upper 32 bits of RDX set to ZERO because EDX is 32-bit dest
movsx %ax, %rdx    # Sign extend 16-bit register to 64-bit register

movsx %eax, %rdx   # Sign extend 32-bit register to 64-bit register
```

Comment: While this is all true information, it doesn't really explain how to do what the OP wants to do. The OP wants to move `eax` into the lower half of `rdx` while preserving the upper half of `rdx`, which none of those do.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica : Unless I am missing something I don't see anything in the question that states he wants to retain the info in the upper 32-bits. First of all there is the question in the title that asks about moving smaller to larger registers. In the question he did ask a further question `then only the low order 32 bits of %rdx get updated?` The answer to that is no since the instruction he is using isn't even valid. Both of those questions I address in my answer.

Comment: That "further question" is what I meant. Although his example instruction is invalid, and it looks like the answer is "it's impossible in a single instruction", wouldn't it be better to say that in the answer, and to show a solution with multiple instructions?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica It isn't clear that he ever intended to do that! At no point did he ask if you could store a smaller register into a larger register and retain the value in the upper portion. My answer (in the table of instructions) points out `mov %eax, %rdx` isn't valid but to do what I believe he is asking I suggested that `mov %eax, %edx` would suffice. I am basing my answer on the premise that since he never said anything about retaining the higher bits, that it is a non issue. If OP is asking for situation of retaining the higher bits then he can accept the other answer.

Comment: I am answering the question I believe that the OP is asking about. But since there is uncertainty as to what the real question is they have a choice between 2 answers. That will be up to the OP. The question is ambiguous since he never established what result he actually wants. Given the question in the title I don't think he understands the basics of moving from narrow to wider registers.

Comment: I agree, I rolled the dice on what OP might mean but I could just as easily have guessed wrong