# Nasm: Print on console

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I made this program that open a image file and find a hidden message in the file. I have to print the message on the console.

i think the part where i open the file and search for the hidden message is right, but i don´t know for sure because i can´t print the output to confirm.

this is the code:

```
; Example program to demonstrate file I/O.
; This example will open/create a file, write some
; information to the file, and close the file.
; Note, the file name is hard-coded for this example.
; This example program will open a file, read the
; contents, and write the contents to the screen.
; This routine also provides some very simple examples
; regarding handling various errors on system services.
; -------------------------------------------------------
section .data
; -----
; Define standard constants.
LF equ 10 ; line feed
NULL equ 0 ; end of string
TRUE equ 1
FALSE equ 0
EXIT_SUCCESS equ 0 ; success code
STDIN equ 0 ; standard input
STDOUT equ 1 ; standard output
STDERR equ 2 ; standard error
SYS_write equ 1; write
SYS_read equ 0 ; read
SYS_open equ 2 ; file open
SYS_close equ 3 ; file close
SYS_exit equ 60 ; terminate
SYS_creat equ 85 ; file open/create
SYS_time equ 201 ; get time
O_CREAT equ 0x40
O_TRUNC equ 0x200
O_APPEND equ 0x400
O_RDONLY equ 000000q ; read only
O_WRONLY equ 000001q ; write only
S_IRUSR equ 00400q
S_IWUSR equ 00200q
S_IXUSR equ 00100q
; -----
; Variables/constants for main.
BUFF_SIZE equ 256
newLine db LF, NULL
db LF, LF, NULL
fileName dq 6
fileDesc dq 0
errMsgOpen db "Error opening the file.", LF, NULL
errMsgRead db "Error reading from the file.", LF, NULL
offset db 1
size db 1
; -------------------------------------------------------
section .bss
readBuffer: resb BUFF_SIZE
; -------------------------------------------------------
section .text
global _start
_start:
xor rax, rax
xor rcx, rcx
xor rdx, rdx
xor rbx, rbx
mov rbx, rsp
mov rax, qword [rbx+16]
mov [fileName], rax
xor rax, rax
push rsp

; Attempt to open file - Use system service for file open

openInputFile:
pop rax ; pop argc value - should be 2
cmp rax, 0x2    
jne done
mov rax, SYS_open ; file open
mov rdi, fileName ; file name string
mov rsi, O_RDONLY ; read only access
syscall ; call the kernel
cmp rax, 0 ; check for success
jl errorOnOpen
mov qword [fileDesc], rax ; save descriptor
; -----
; Read from file.
;
mov rax, SYS_read
mov rdi, qword [fileDesc]
mov rsi, readBuffer
mov rdx, BUFF_SIZE
syscall
cmp rax, 0
jl errorOnRead
; -----
; Print the buffer.
; add the NULL for the print string
mov rax, qword [readBuffer+2] ;SSSS
mov qword [size], rax
mov rax, qword [readBuffer+10] ;OOOO
mov [offset], rax
mov rcx, 0


ler: ;ler um caracter
mov rbp, 0
xor rbx, rbx
xor rdx, rdx

lerloop:
inc rax
cmp rax, [size]
je errorOnRead

saltaQuartobyte:
inc ecx
cmp ecx, 4
jne continua
inc rax ;incremneta rax outra vez para saltar o quarto
cmp rax, [size]
je errorOnRead
mov ecx, 0

continua:
mov bl, byte [readBuffer+rax]
shl rdx, 1
shr rbx, 1
adc rdx, 0

inc rbp
cmp rbp, 7 ;fim do caracter ASCII, 0X 0XXX XXXX
jne lerloop

mov rdi, rdx
call printString ; imprime caracter ASCII

cmp rax, [size] ;comea o priximo
jne ler
; -----
; Close the file.

mov rax, SYS_close
mov rdi, qword [fileDesc]
syscall
jmp done
; -----
; Error on open.

errorOnOpen:
mov rdi, errMsgOpen
call printString
jmp done

; Error on read.

errorOnRead:
mov rdi, errMsgRead
call printString
jmp done
; -----
; program done.
done:
mov rax, SYS_exit
mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
syscall

; **********************************************************
; Generic procedure to display a string to the screen.

global printString
printString:
push rbp

mov rbp, rsp
push rbp
; -----
; Call OS to output string.
mov rax, SYS_write ; code for write()
mov rsi, rdi ; addr of characters
mov rdi, STDOUT ; file descriptor
; count set above
syscall ; system call
; -----
; String printed, return to calling routine.
prtDone:
pop rbx
pop rbp
ret
```

this is my last attempt of the print but the program still don't print anything, and I don't understand why? or what's wrong?

Comment: Does the print string function work if you give it a bogus file name?

Comment: There’s a comment in print string that the count is “set above”, but I don’t see that, at least not when print string is used to print an error message.

Comment: @prl that is my last attempt... it was based on this code https://codeshare.io/2pvOmY

Answer (score 1):

#### A fundamental error

> ```
> push rsp
>
> ; Attempt to open file - Use system service for file open
>
> openInputFile:
> pop rax ; pop argc value - should be 2
> cmp rax, 0x2    
> jne done
> mov rax, SYS_open ; file open
> ```

Your program starts with copying the stackpointer `RSP` to the accumulator `RAX`, and then compares to see if the value is 2, but *when is the stackpointer ever going to be 2*? And so, **the program will always prematurely exit**. No wonder that nothing gets printed.

#### A selection of other errors

> ```
> offset db 1
> size db 1
> ...
> mov rax, qword [readBuffer+2] ;SSSS
> mov qword [size], rax
> mov rax, qword [readBuffer+10] ;OOOO
> mov [offset], rax
> ```

You have reserved not enough room to store the qwords *size* and *offset*!

Better store them in the .bss section using `resq`:

```
section .bss
readBuffer: resb BUFF_SIZE
offset      resq 1
size        resq 1
```

---

> ```
> mov rax, qword [readBuffer+2] ;SSSS
> mov qword [size], rax
> mov rax, qword [readBuffer+10] ;OOOO
> mov [offset], rax
> ```

If the file is a .BMP (I'm considering those well-known offsets), then the *size* and *offset* fields are actually **dwords**. You would have to write instead (loading `EAX` automatically zero extends the value into `RAX`):

```
mov   eax, [readBuffer+2] ;SSSS
mov   [size], rax
mov   eax, [readBuffer+10] ;OOOO
mov   [offset], rax
```

---

> ```
> printString:
> push rbp
> mov rbp, rsp
> push rbp    <<<<
> ...
> pop rbx     <<<<
> pop rbp
> ret
> ```

Because of the mismatch, you're destroying `RBX` on return.

The [code that you used](https://codeshare.io/2pvOmY) depends on calculating the length of the ASCIIZ string. You cannot just leave that out!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But it's still not printing :'(

Comment: I don’t think there’s an instruction *movzx r64, r/m32*. Since writing a 32 bit register always clears the upper half of the 64-bit register, there’s no need for movzx. Just use *mov r32, r/m32*.

Comment: @prl: There isn't - my answer on [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51387571) explains why in terms of instruction encoding and ISA design choices.  An overly forgiving assembler might allow it in the source and encode it as `mov r32, r/m32`, but NASM and YASM don't.  So yeah that change was necessary as well as a good idea.