# Are a 64-bit register's higher 4 bytes set to zero if we only use mov operation on its lower 4 bytes

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64

I am learning x86-64 assembly from Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective and I came across an exercise which asks to translate a line of C code into (two) equivalent assembly instructions. The code is about copying a variable of one type into another using pointers.

The pointer variables are declared as follows:

```
src_t *sp; //src_t and dest_t are typedefs
dest_t *dp;
```

and the C code to be translated is:

```
*dp = (dest_t)*sp;
```

It is given that the pointers `sp` and `dp` are stored in registers `%rdi` and `%rsi` respectively, and that we should set the 'appropriate portion' of `%rax` (eg. `%eax`, `%ax` or `%al`) to do intermediate data copying (as x86-64 doesn't allow both source and destination to be memory references).

Now when `src_t` is `unsigned char` and `dest_t` is `long`, I did the following assembly code for it:

```
movzbq (%rdi), %rax //move a byte into %rax with zero extension
movq %rax, (%rsi) //move 8 bytes of 'long' data
```

But the book as well as [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7YPz3eqsa) (using `gcc` with `-O3`) says it should be

```
movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
movq    %rax, (%rsi)
```

In this case, the byte is only(?) zero-extended to 4 bytes (`%eax` is 4 bytes long), but I read that if we do like

```
movl %edx, %rax
```

then the upper 4 bytes of %rax will also be set to 0.

I have two questions:

1. Is `movl %edx, %rax` equivalent to `movl %edx, %eax`, that is, are the upper 4 bytes also set to 0 in the latter case?
2. Is `movzbq (%rdi), %rax` equivalent to `movzbl (%rdi), %eax`, i.e. does `movzbl` also set the higher 4 bytes to zero (like `movl`), even though we *don't mention the full register* (`%rax`) but *only a part of it* (`%eax)`?

Comment: (1) the former instruction doesn't exist (2) correct.  All operations targetting dword sized registers clear the upper  32 bit of the destination.

Comment: @fuz for (1) this means that both source and destination registers have to match the instruction suffix..thanks for clarification

Comment: It depends on the instruction, but usually, yes.

Comment: @tf3: Yup, only a very few instructions can use different-sized operands.  e.g. `shl %cl, %rax`, and movzx / movsx (AT&T movsXY / movzXY where XY are 2 different size codes).  See also [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51387571) and [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137), and yes, `movzbq` is encodeable but a waste of a REX prefix to explicitly widen instead of implicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, on x86_64, any instruction with a 32-bit general purpose register as its destination (any %eXX or %rNd register) will also set the upper 32 bits of the corresponding 64-bit register to 0.  So every instruction with a 32-bit destination 0-extends that to 64 bits.

From the Intel IA32 Software Developer's manual (section 3.4.1.1):

> When in 64-bit mode, operand size determines the number of valid bits in the destination general-purpose
> register:
>
> - 64-bit operands generate a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose register.
> - 32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose
>   register.
> - 8-bit and 16-bit operands generate an 8-bit or 16-bit result. The upper 56 bits or 48 bits (respectively) of the
>   destination general-purpose register are not modified by the operation. If the result of an 8-bit or 16-bit
>   operation is intended for 64-bit address calculation, explicitly sign-extend the register to the full 64-bits.

Comment: Thanks for the crisp manual entry