# Why doesn't MOVZX work when operands have the same size?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, instruction-set, mov

With `Z2 dword ?`, `mov eax, Z2` works fine but `movzx eax, Z2` gives "invalid instruction operands" error.

I am a little confused here: even though *Z2* is of same size as `eax`,
why couldn't assembly just accept `movzx` for this? It seems that `movzx` specifically wants that the operands are not of same size.

What could be the reason for designing an instruction like this?

Wouldn't it be easier to code if it was designed to simply allow operands of same size?

Comment: If the sizes are the same, there's nothing to extend, is there?

Comment: `movzx` stands for “move zero extend.”  There's nothing to extend when both operands are the same size, so such an instruction does not exist.

Comment: _Wouldn't it be easier to code if it was designed to simply allow operands of same size_ Can you show an example where you think `movzx` of the same size would be useful, because I find `movzx` on same-size operands quite useless since no 0-extension will happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work (in machine code), inefficiently.
That's why most assemblers stop you from shooting yourself in the foot.

---

> What could be the reason for designing an instruction like this ?

To perform zero-extension from narrow source data.
That's what the ZX in the mnemonic means.

If you have same-sized operands, you're expected to use `mov`,
not try to use a zero-extending or sign-extending copy instruction.

---

Just like with MOVSXD, even when it's possible to use the MOVZX opcode to encode an instruction equivalent to `mov r, r/m16`, it's not recommended for efficiency reasons.

Like [Intel says for MOVSXD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd): *The use of MOVSXD without REX.W* (which would encode `movsxd r32, r/m32`) *is discouraged. Regular MOV should be used instead of using MOVSXD without REX.W.*  (I took out the "in 64-bit mode" from the quote because that's redundant; `movsxd` only exists in 64-bit mode; the opcode means something else in other modes.)

---

**Anyway yes, it is possible to `movzx ax, bx` in x86 machine code, but assemblers save you from yourself and refuse to assemble that inefficient instruction.**  (2-byte opcode instead of 1 for `mov`; `movzx` was new in 386 and all the 1-byte opcodes were already used up before that.)

> Copies the contents of the source operand (register or memory location) to the destination operand (register) and zero extends the value. **The size of the converted value depends on the operand-size attribute.**
> https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx

I tested it on my Skylake CPU with the following NASM source, written to probably assemble with MASM as well.  (e.g. `db  66h` instead of using an `o16` NASM prefix on the `movzx` line.)

```
mov  edx, -1
xor  eax,eax
db   66h             ; operand-size prefix that we're not telling the assembler about
movzx  eax, dx

mov  ax, dx          ; for comparison
```

(super minimal, taking advantage of toolchain defaults for this one-off that's never intended to be a proper program.)

```
$ nasm -felf64 movzx.asm && ld -o movzx  movzx.o 
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000
$ objdump -drwC -Mintel  ./movzx
...
  401000:       ba ff ff ff ff          mov    edx,0xffffffff
  401005:       48 b8 cc cc cc cc 44 33 22 11   movabs rax,0x11223344cccccccc
  40100f:       66 0f b7 c2             movzx  ax,dx
  401013:       66 89 d0                mov    ax,dx       # note it's shorter.  
          # Fun fact: we can see NASM picked the mov r/m16, r form, since the ModRM byte is different.
```

Interestingly, the disassembler in GNU Binutils (objdump -d and GDB) decodes it as `movzx ax, dx`, or `movzww  %dx, %ax` in AT&T syntax.

Using `gdb ./movzx` on the static executable, I used `layout reg` and `starti` / `stepi` to step through and see registers change:

`66 0f b7 c2  movzx  ax,dx` executes normally, and
changes RAX from `0x11223344cccccccc` to `0x11223344ccccffff`, proving that it behaved exactly like a 16-bit `mov`, not touching any upper bytes of RAX.  (Including not implicitly zero-extending the upper 32 bits of RAX, like a write to EAX would have.)

(Then quit GDB because I didn't include code to exit, only the code I actually wanted to single-step.)

---

This is impossible for `movzx al, dl` -  16-bit vs. 32 vs. 64-bit operand-size is selected by `66` or REX prefixes to override the mode's default, but 8-bit operand-size is only set via the opcode.  There's no prefix that can override an instruction to 8-bit operand-size.  And of course  there's no form of `movzx` with an 8-bit destination operand.  (If you want to zero-extend a nibble to a byte, copy and `and reg, 0x0f`.)

---

### Assemblers that allow it: just GAS in `.intel_syntax` mode?

NASM and YASM reject `movzx ax, dx`
So does `clang` (with `.intel_syntax noprefix`).
But `llvm-objdump -d` will disassemble it the same as GNU Binutils.

But **GNU Binutils** not only disassembles it (Intel `movzx  ax,dx`, AT&T `movzww  %dx, %ax`), it (GNU `as`) **accepts** the Intel-syntax version.  GAS:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
    movzx  ax, dx             # works, producing the above machine code.

.att_syntax
    movzw   %dx, %ax         # Error: operand size mismatch for `movzw'
    movzww  %dx, %ax         # Error: invalid instruction suffix for `movzw'
```

---

Related:

- [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387571/movzx-missing-32-bit-register-to-64-bit-register)

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that movzx specifically wants that the operands are not of same size

`movzx` specifically wants the destination to be larger than the source.

> why couldn't assembly just accept movzx for this

In theory; there's no reason an assembler couldn't accept "`movzx` (the mnemonic) with operands that are the same size" and silently generate a `mov` (the opcode) instead.

> What could be the reason for designing an instruction like this ?

Humans make mistakes. For all programming languages it's better if mistakes are detected and reported as soon as possible (ideally, in the IDE so you don't even have to compile or assemble before you find the mistake; and never detected by a normal user and reported via. a bug report after the software is published).

For "`movzx` with same size operands", it's more likely to be a mistake (e.g. programmer wanted something smaller to be extended with zeros to become something larger but they mistyped an operand) than it is to be intentional (given that `mov` would've been easier to type); so it's better for the assembler to treat it as an error so that (if it is a mistake) the programmer knows about it sooner.

Note that there are cases where some "convenient silent replacement done by assembler" would be beneficial. One example is `movzx rax,eax`, where it's obvious the programmer wanted something smaller to be extended with zeros to become something larger; but where it's better for the assembler to generate a `mov eax,eax` given that the CPU will zero extend by default.