# "movl" instruction in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att

I am learning assembly and reading "Computer Systems: A programmer's perspective". In Practice Problem 3.3, it says `movl  %eax,%rdx` will generate an error. The answer keys says `movl  %eax,%dx  Destination operand incorrect size`. I am not sure if this is a typo or not, but my question is: is `movl  %eax,%rdx` a legal instruction? I think it is moving the 32 bits in `%eax` with zero extension to `%rdx`, which will not be generated as `movzql` since

> an instruction generating a 4-byte value with a register as the destination will fill the upper 4 bytes with zeros` (from the book).

I tried to write some C code to generate it, but I always get `movslq  %eax, %rdx`(GCC 4.8.5 -Og). I am completely confused.

Comment: both operands have to have the same size. dx is 16bit , eax 32 bits.

Comment: The `%dx` in the answer is probably a typo and should be `%rdx` to match the question. Note that if you are using the Global Edition, its exercises and typos are filled with severe errors and should probably be ignored altogether.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998998/csapp-example-uses-idivq-with-two-operands

Comment: If you're getting `movslq`, apparently you used signed `int` instead of `unsigned` or `uint32_t`.  C semantics require sign-extension when promoting a signed type to any wider type, preserving the value.  So cast to unsigned first, or `long foo(unsigned x){ return x; }`.   https://godbolt.org/z/YhevPfEvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU assembler doesn't accept `movl %eax,%rdx`.  It also doesn't make sense for the encoding, since `mov` must have a single operand size (using a prefix byte if needed), not two different sized operands.

The effect you want is achieved by `movl %eax, %edx` since writes to a 32-bit register always zero-extend into the corresponding 64-bit register.  See [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6/11177225#11177225).

`movzlq %eax, %rdx` might make logical sense, but it's not supported since it would be redundant.

Comment: Just to clarify, `movl %eax, %edx` is equivalent to `movzlq %eax, %rdx` so `movzlq` is redundant, right?

Comment: @jeffma: I guess I would say that if `movzlq %eax, %rdx` did exist, it would be equivalent to `movl %eax, %edx`, which is why it does not exist.

Comment: @jeffma: [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51387571) goes into more detail about why no special mnemonic for that exists, because 32-bit `mov` does the job.