# Adding another word in .data is messing up with values in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I created a simple code to make a summation (currently the first 20 numbers). Everything goes fine, even the functions I made to print a number. There's a single problem: I can't use both words I allocated at `.data`.

```
section .data 
    total dw 0
    index dw 1
```

If I add `index` to `.data`, the value of `[total]` goes from 0 to 65536. `index`'s is still 1, and I don't have any clue of why this is happening.

I removed the loops and instructions in `_sum20` to shorten the pasted code (I tested it).

```
section .data 
    total dw 0
    index dw 1

_start:
    call _sum20         
    call _printInt     
    end                 

_sum20:
    mov rax, [total] ; rax = 65536
    ret
```

In the code above, `[total]` has a value of 65536

```
section .data 
    total dw 0


_start:
    call _sum20         
    call _printInt     
    end                 

_sum20:
    mov rax, [total] ; rax = 0
    ret
```

Here, `[total]`'s value is 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple: you defined `total` and `data` to be words, i.e. 2 byte quantities but then accessed the variables using quad word, i.e. 8 byte operations.  This oversized memory access causes not just one variable, but also some unrelated memory after it to be affected.

To fix this problem, either change `total` and `data` to be quad word variables using the `dq` instead of `dw` directive, or change your code to access these variables with a 16 bit data size.  For example, in your case you could do:

```
movzx rax, word [total]
```

Comment: For `movzx` (unlike `movsx`), there's never a reason to make the destination explicitly 64-bit.  `movzx eax, word [total]` would do exactly the same thing, saving a byte of code size (no REX prefix). [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) and related: [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51387571)

Comment: @PeterCordes I have done it this wy to clearly illustrate the idea without having to explain why we write to `eax` and obtain a 64 bit value.

Comment: My comment was more aimed at future readers as an addendum to your answer.  I realize you wrote it this way to minimize changes vs. the code in the question.  But `movzx r64, src` is a sub-optimal idiom that people shouldn't learn, always use `movzx r32, src`