# What is the meaning of 'mov %reg8, (%reg32)' (not movb)?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, opcode

the test platform is `x86-32bit`.

I know that on `x86-32bit`, we have two opcodes `movsbl` and `movzbl` which has the following semantics:

```
%eax = 0x12345678
%edx = 0xAAAABBBB
MOVB %dh, %al         %eax = 0x123456BB
MOVSBL %dh, %eax      %eax = 0xFFFFFFBB
MOVZBL %dh, %eax      %eax = 0x000000BB
```

The above example is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861095/what-does-movsbl-instruction-do).

Then I am kind of confused with the semantics of the following instruction:

```
mov %dl, 0x2c(%esp)
```

What is the exact meaning of the above `mov`, is it equal to `movsbl` ? or equal to `movzbl`? Or neither?

Comment: Neither, that is a simple 8 bit move. It will only write a single byte of memory. Note it is not `mem32` it's `mem8` (implicit due to the 8 bit register used).

Comment: Thank you @Jester. So you mean it actually equals to `movb %dl, 0x2c(%esp)` ?

Comment: Yes, it generates the exact same machine code. The assembler deduced the `b` size from the register used.

Comment: @Jester, got it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no operand sizes are explicitly provided, most assemblers will calculate the type of operation from the operand sizes. Therefore, in this case, `mov %dl, 0x2c(%esp)` is equivalent to `movb %dl, 0x2c(%esp)`, a simple 1 byte move, deducing the `b` suffix from the one-byte register, `dl`.

The reason for the 32 bit register: this stores the address of the memory location; no mismatch in operand sizes results (since a memory location can be interpreted as being any size).