# Can someone help make sense of this assembly code to try reverse engineer?

Tags: c, assembly

Heres an `disas` of a function which takes input and stops a bomb from exploding.

```
0x00000000004011ca <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp                 #reserve 8 bytes on stack
0x00000000004011ce <+4>:     cmpb   $0x37,0x1(%rdi)           #compare 0x37 ('7') with second character of input
0x00000000004011d2 <+8>:     jne    0x4011df <phase_1+21>     #explode bomb if not equal
0x00000000004011d4 <+10>:    cmpb   $0x5d,0x2(%rdi)           #compare 0x5d (']') with third character of input
0x00000000004011d8 <+14>:    jne    0x4011df <phase_1+21>     #explode bomb if not equal
0x00000000004011da <+16>:    cmpb   $0x5a,(%rdi)              #compare 0x5a ('Z') with first character of input
0x00000000004011dd <+19>:    je     0x4011ed <phase_1+35>     #if all equal, skip bomb explosion
0x00000000004011df <+21>:    callq  0x401c01 <bomb_ignition>  #bomb explode
0x00000000004011e4 <+26>:    mov    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax  #rax = -1
0x00000000004011eb <+33>:    jmp    0x401200 <phase_1+54>     #end 
0x00000000004011ed <+35>:    movsbl 0xf(%rdi),%eax            //need help here
0x00000000004011f1 <+39>:    add    $0x1b,%eax
0x00000000004011f4 <+42>:    movsbl 0xe(%rdi),%edx
0x00000000004011f8 <+46>:    cmp    %edx,%eax
0x00000000004011fa <+48>:    sete   %al
0x00000000004011fd <+51>:    movzbl %al,%eax
0x0000000000401200 <+54>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000401204 <+58>:    retq
```

I have annotated what i think its doing with `#`. Please tell me if im wrong anywhere. I need help in figuring out what its doing at and after the first `movsbl`. From just reading, I think it extends `%rdi` by 15, then puts it in `%eax`. then adds 27. To what, I dont know. Then it extends `%rdi` by 14 and put it in `%edx`. It compares, and if equal, then sets flag `%al`? Then moves `%al` to `%eax`. Then clears up stack space. Then returns.

Did I go wrong anywhere in my understanding of anything? Can someone clarify what `movsbl` is doing in this? ANY HELP APPRECIATED. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861095/what-does-movsbl-instruction-do

Comment: @MitchWheat Ive seen that, and ones like it. They all seem to go over my head and dont seem to clearly explain what it does or why the examples behave the way they do (imo).  Would you mind explaining it as if i was 5

Comment: If this were written as `mov 0xf(%rdi),%eax` would it make more sense to you?  You can't (quite) write that, since the source (`0xf(%rdi)`) is intended to be a byte, and the destination is a 32bit int (`eax`).  Since the destination is 32bits long, you have to tell the assembler what to do with the other 24bits.  Telling it to extend the sign bit (ie if the byte is negative, make the int negative) is one way of doing that.

Comment: `movsbl` is a **sign-extending load from memory** from 8-bit to 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
movsbl 0xf(%rdi),%eax
```

`movsbl` is move byte to long using **s**ign extension, so `int8_t` is promoted to `int32_t`; i.e.

```
int32_t eax = *((int8_t *)(rdi + 0xf));
```

This means that the [*signed* value as interpreted according to the two's complement stays the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so if the `int8_t` held e.g. `-1`, the `int32_t` would also hold `-1`. However if interpreted as unsigned, the corresponding values would be `0xFF` and `0xFFFFFFFF` which clearly are not the same. Unsigned promotion would zero-extend instead, so using `movzbl` here would extend `0xFF` to `0x000000FF`; zero extension ensures that the *unsigned value after the extension is the same*.

Then another not so obvious instruction is

```
sete   %al
```

Which is equal to

```
uint8_t al = <previous comparison equal/set zero flag> ? 1: 0;
```

Setting `al` does not reset the rest of the bits in `eax`, `rax`, so, the instruction

```
movzbl %al,%eax
```

moves byte to long, using **z**ero extension, i.e. unsigned promotion:

```
uint32_t eax = (uint8_t)al;
```

This essentially zeroes all the higher order bits 8-**63** in `rax`, because setting `eax` would also reset the higher order bits.

The default return value is in the accumulator, so the function returns either `1` or `0` and all `intN_t` and `uintN_t` for N of 8, 16, 32, 64 would work alike for the return type in the prototype.