# why is movsbl instead of movzbl while converting char to unsigned

Tags: c++, compilation

```
int main(){
    unsigned *dp;
    char *sp;
    *dp = *sp;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I got movsbl rather than movzbl while converting a char type to unsigned.
Could someone kindly explain? Thx in advance!

**Extra**:
Compiled code:

```
    call    __main
    movsbl  0, %eax
    movl    %eax, 0
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861177/7582247) answer your question?

Comment: See [integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).  Presumably `char` is signed on your system.  It has lower rank than `int`, so `*sp` is promoted to `int` before assigning to `*dp`, and that means sign extension.

Comment: @TedLyngmo my question is why isn't zero extend

Comment: @NateEldredge why isn't zero extend

Comment: @HelloWorld: Zero extension would give the wrong result.  If `*sp` had the value `-1` (i.e. `0xff` on a typical machine), then `*sp` gets promoted to `int`, the int `-1`.  You are then converting `-1` to unsigned, which is defined to have wrap-around two's-complement behavior.  The result assigned to `*dp` must be `0xffffffff` (assuming 32-bit `unsigned int`).  Zero extension would yield `0x000000ff` in that case, which is wrong.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes,  0xffffffff  = -1, but why isn't the expected value equle to 1 since the destination type is unsigned?

Comment: @HelloWorld: Are you thinking that converting signed to unsigned should take the absolute value?  It doesn't.  It wraps around mod 2^32 or whatever the maximum value of `unsigned` is.  See C17 6.3.1.3p2.  On a two's-complement machine this reduces to "use the same bits and treat them as an `unsigned`".

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, thx!

Comment: _"my question is why isn't zero extend"_ -  I got that and thought it was answered in the answers I linked to, but @NateEldredge seems to have done a better job explaining it :-)