# Assembly Language: cbw

Tags: assembly, x86, division, sign-extension

I am unsure of what the `cbw` command actually does. I have a snippet of code:

```
mov  ax,0FF0h
cbw
idiv ah
```

How does the value of ax change after cbw?

Comment: Look it up in any copy of Intel or AMD's ISA reference manual: 
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CBW:CWDE:CDQE.html.  See also [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36464879) and also [What does cltq do in assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/a/45386217) for a table of cbw / cwde / cwd / etc. equivalents in terms of movsx, for both Intel and AT&T syntax.

Comment: Dividing by `AH` after sign-extending into AX is exceptionally weird.  It will fault for non-negative AL (because AH=0), or it will divide by `-1` for negative AL.  (Again faulting with `#DE` for AL=80h, because -128 / -1 = +128 overflows 8-bit AL.)  This is like the worst most inefficient attempt to take the absolute value of AL.

Comment: @PeterCordes `cbw`, `cwde`, `cdqe` all three uses same opcode. So how does processor chooses `al->ax`, `ax->eax`, `eax->rax` ?   Same for `cwd`, `cdq`, `cqo` triplet.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: Prefixes, exactly like for other 16/32/64-bit opcodes.  You can even see the full machine code including prefixes for all of those instructions in my answer I already linked in my first comment, [What does cltq do in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45386217).  For details of prefixes, see [Is there a default operand size in the x86-64 (AMD64) architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68289333)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `cbw` instruction sign-extends a byte into a word. In this case, it'll take the sign bit of `AL` (which happens to be 1) and copy it into every bit of `AH`.

This means that the two's-complement value of `AX` will be the same, but the binary representation will be different.

The value of `AX` after the `cbw` instruction will be `FFF0h` (a 16-bit -16 value, just like `AL` was originally an 8-bit -16)

Comment: Thanks. I understand your explanation of the sign bit of `AL` being 1, since it is negative, but I am a bit confused as to why `AL` is originally an 8-bit -1. Isn't `AL` -16 originally (with the sign bit equal to 1)?

Comment: The last zero in 0FF0h was overlooked. AX should become 0FFF0h after CBW.