# Translating Go assembler to NASM

Tags: go, assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

I came across the following Go code:

```
type Element [12]uint64

//go:noescape
func CSwap(x, y *Element, choice uint8)

//go:noescape
func Add(z, x, y *Element)
```

where the `CSwap` and `Add` functions are basically coming from an assembly, and look like the following:

```
TEXT ·CSwap(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-17

    MOVQ    x+0(FP), REG_P1
    MOVQ    y+8(FP), REG_P2
    MOVB    choice+16(FP), AL   // AL = 0 or 1
    MOVBLZX AL, AX              // AX = 0 or 1
    NEGQ    AX                  // RAX = 0x00..00 or 0xff..ff

    MOVQ    (0*8)(REG_P1), BX
    MOVQ    (0*8)(REG_P2), CX
    // Rest removed for brevity

TEXT ·Add(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-24

    MOVQ    z+0(FP), REG_P3
    MOVQ    x+8(FP), REG_P1
    MOVQ    y+16(FP), REG_P2

    MOVQ    (REG_P1), R8
    MOVQ    (8)(REG_P1), R9
    MOVQ    (16)(REG_P1), R10
    MOVQ    (24)(REG_P1), R11
    // Rest removed for brevity
```

What I try to do is that translate the assembly to a syntax that is more familiar to me (I think mine is more like NASM), while the above syntax is Go assembler. Regarding the `Add` method I didn't have much problem, and translated it correctly (according to test results). It looks like this in my case:

```
.text
.global add_asm
add_asm:
  push   r12
  push   r13
  push   r14
  push   r15

  mov    r8, [reg_p1]
  mov    r9, [reg_p1+8]
  mov    r10, [reg_p1+16]
  mov    r11, [reg_p1+24]
  // Rest removed for brevity
```

But, I have a problem when translating the `CSwap` function, I have something like this:

```
.text
.global cswap_asm
cswap_asm:
  push   r12
  push   r13
  push   r14

  mov    al, 16
  mov    rax, al
  neg    rax

  mov    rbx, [reg_p1+(0*8)]
  mov    rcx, [reg_p2+(0*8)]
```

But this doesn't seem to be quite correct, as I get error when compiling it. Any ideas how to translate the above `CSwap` assembly part to something like NASM?

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**

Okay, after the two answers below, and some testing and digging, I found out that the code uses the following three registers for parameter passing:

```
#define reg_p1  rdi
#define reg_p2  rsi
#define reg_p3  rdx
```

Accordingly, `rdx` has the value of the `choice` parameter. So, all that I had to do was use this:

```
movzx  rax, dl // Get the lower 8 bits of rdx (reg_p3)
neg    rax
```

Using `byte [rdx]` or `byte [reg_3]` was giving an error, but using `dl`  seems to work fine for me.

Comment: This is definitely not gas btw, it's Go assembler.

Comment: You can always check your translation by assembling with the Go assembler and using a disassembler (like `objdump -drwC -Mintel`) on the object file.  That gives you GNU `.intel_syntax`, which is MASM-like, but it's pretty easy to read when you're used to NASM.

Comment: Your translation of the Go `Add` into NASM `add_asm` looks wrong, you're missing the part where you load the parameters into `REG_P1`, `REG_P2`, and `REG_P3`. From how they `REG_P1` etc.. look like registers, but who knows what registers.

Comment: because `mov` wants 2 operands of the same size, try `movzx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic docs about Go's asm: https://golang.org/doc/asm.  It's not totally equivalent to NASM or AT&T syntax: `FP` is a pseudo-register name for whichever register it decides to use as the frame pointer.  (Typically RSP or RBP).  Go asm also seems to omit function prologue (and probably epilogue) instructions.  [As @RossRidge comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932759/translating-go-assembler-to-nasm/47933661?noredirect=1#comment82845672_47933661), it's a bit more like a internal representation like LLVM IR than truly asm.

Go also has its own object-file format, so I'm not sure you can make Go-compatible object files with NASM.

**If you want to call this function from something other than Go, you'll also need to port the code to a different calling convention**.  Go appears to be using a stack-args calling convention even for x86-64, unlike the normal x86-64 System V ABI or the x86-64 Windows calling convention.  (Or maybe those `mov` function args into `REG_P1` and so on instructions disappear when Go builds this source for a register-arg calling convention?)

(This is why you could you had to use `movzx eax, dl` instead of loading from the stack at all.)

BTW, rewriting this code in C instead of NASM would probably make even more sense if you want to use it with C.  Small functions are best inlined and optimized away by the compiler.

---

It would be a good idea to check your translation, or get a starting point, by assembling with the Go assembler and using a disassembler.

`objdump -drwC -Mintel` or [Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler](http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv) would be good, but they don't understand Go's object-file format.  If Go has a tool to extract the actual machine code or get it in an ELF object file, do that.

If not, you could use `ndisasm -b 64` (which treats input files as flat binaries, disassembling *all* the bytes as if they were instructions).  You can specify an offset/length if you can find out where the function starts.  x86 instructions are variable length, and disassembly will likely be "out of sync" at the start of the function.  You might want to add a bunch of single-byte NOP instructions (kind of a NOP sled) for the disassembler, so if it decodes some 0x90 bytes as part of an immediate or disp32 for a long instruction that was really not part of the function, it will be in sync.  (But the function prologue will still be messed up).

You might add some "signpost" instructions to your Go asm functions to make it easy to find the right place in the mess of crazy asm from disassembling metadata as instructions.  e.g. put a `pmuludq xmm0, xmm0` in there somewhere, or some other instruction with a unique mnemonic that you can search for which the Go code doesn't include.  Or an instruction with an immediate that will stand out, like `addq $0x1234567, SP`.  (An instruction that will crash so you don't forget to take it out again is good here.)

Or you could use `gdb`'s built-in disassembler: add an instruction that will segfault (like a load from a bogus absolute address (`movl 0, AX` null-pointer deref), or a register holding a non-pointer value e.g. `movl (AX), AX`).  Then you'll have an instruction-pointer value for the instructions in memory, and can disassemble from some point behind that.  (Probably the function start will be 16-byte aligned.)

---

### Specific instructions.

`MOVBLZX AL, AX` reads AL, so that's definitely an 8-bit operand.  The size for AX is given by the `L` part of the mnemonic, meaning `long` for 32 bit, like in GAS AT&T syntax.  (The gas mnemonic for that form of `movzx` is `movzbl %al, %eax`).  See [What does cltq do in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555094/what-does-cltq-do-in-assembly/45386217#45386217) for a table of cdq / cdqe and the AT&T equivalent, and the AT&T / Intel mnemonic for the equivalent MOVSX instruction.

The NASM instruction you want is `movzx eax, al`.  Using `rax` as the destination would be a waste of a REX prefix.  Using `ax` as the destination would be a mistake: it wouldn't zero-extend into the full register, and would leave whatever high garbage.  Go asm syntax for x86 is very confusing when you're not used to it, because AX can mean AX, EAX, or RAX depending on the operand size.

Obviously `mov rax, al` isn't a possibility: Like most instructions, `mov`  requires both its operands to be the same size.  `movzx` is one of the rare exceptions.

---

`MOVB    choice+16(FP), AL` is a byte load into `AL`, not an immediate move.  `choice+16` is a an offset from `FP`.  This syntax is basically the same as AT&T addressing modes, with FP as a register and `choice` as an assemble-time constant.

`FP` is a pseudo-register name.  It's pretty clear that it should simply be loading the low byte of the 3rd arg-passing slot, because `choice` is the name of a function arg.  (In Go asm, `choice` is just syntactic sugar, or a constant defined as zero.)

Before a `call` instruction, `rsp` points at the first stack arg, so that + 16 is the 3rd arg.  It appears that `FP` is that base address (and might actually be `rsp+8` or something).  After a `call` (which pushes an 8 byte return address), the 3rd stack arg is at `rsp + 24`.  After more pushes, the offset will be even larger, so adjust as necessary to reach the right location.

If you're porting this function to be called with a standard calling convention, the 3 integer args will be passed in registers, with no stack args.  Which 3 registers depends on whether you're building for Windows vs. non-Windows.  (See Agner Fog's calling conventions doc: http://agner.org/optimize/)

---

**BTW, a byte load into AL and then `movzx eax, al` is just dumb**.  Much more efficient on all modern CPUs to do it in one step with

```
movzx  eax, byte [rsp + 24]      ; or rbp+32 if you made a stack frame.
```

I hope the source in the question is from un-optimized Go compiler output?  Or the assembler itself makes such optimizations?

Comment: Choice is actually the name of the parameter in the Go function.

Comment: Also, I get an error: operation size mismatch for ‘movzx’

Comment: @terett: I had another look, I think FP is a register name, either RSP or RBP.  The right offset to reach `choice` will depend on how many pushes you did.

Comment: @terett: what NASM source line gave you that error for `movzx`?  `movzx  eax, byte [valid_mem_address]` should assemble just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure `objdump` will work, as Go apparently has its own object file format. It's assembly language also isn't quite real assembly language either, it's a bit more like a internal representation like LLVM's IL. The FP register is pseudo-register that doesn't correspond to any real register. The operand `choice+16(FP)` just means the third argument, the `choice` part is ignored. There's some basic documentation about Go's "assembly" language on their web site: https://golang.org/doc/asm

Comment: I guess @RossRidge is right. I did run `go tool asm test.s`, which generated `test.o` for me. But when I run `objconv -fnasm test.o`, I got an error message saying: Error 2018: Unknown type 0x6F206F67 for file: test.o. Also if I run `objdump -drwC -Mintel test.o`, I get an error: objdump: test.o: File format not recognized.

Comment: @PeterCordes Also, if I do something like `movzx  eax, byte [rsp + 16]` (same for `rbp` too), I still get an Error: operand size mismatch for movzx
exit code: 1. But if I separate them such as `mov al, byte [rsp + 16]` then `movzx eax, al`, it compiles, but the result is still wrong, I guess I'm not getting the value of the third parameter which is `u8` variable.

Comment: Okay, I found the solution, and put it in the edited question. Though, your answer helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @terett: `movzx  eax, byte [rsp + 16]` assembles just fine with NASM and YASM.  If you're getting an error from "something like" that, whatever you tried wasn't close enough, or you have a macro `%define` that's breaking something.  Perhaps you `%define byte` to the empty string?  But that gives "operation size not specified" rather than mismatch.

Comment: @RossRidge: Thanks.  Updated the disassembly suggestion with stuff that doesn't need to understand the object file format.

Comment: @terett: Oh, you didn't say you wanted to call your NASM functions from something other than Go.  That makes sense in hindsight, but yes, of course you have to port it to another calling convention instead of just transliterating all the instructions.  You're correct that you don't need to load args from memory at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can translate these as just

```
mov rbx, [reg_p1]
mov rcx, [reg_p2]
```

Unless I'm missing some subtlety, the offsets which are zero can just be ignored. The `*8` isn't a size hint since that's already in the instruction.

The rest of your code looks wrong though. The `MOVB choice+16(FP), AL` in the original is supposed to be fetching the `choice` argument into AL, but you're setting AL to a constant 16, and the code for loading the other arguments seems to be completely missing, as is the code for all of the arguments in the other function.

Comment: You can ignore the `(0*8)` part, as I have partially removed the code, that part is repeated down also from `(1*8)` to `(11*8)`. The problem is that I do not know  how to translate the following three lines:     `MOVB    choice+16(FP), AL
    MOVBLZX AL, AX
    NEGQ    AX`

And in the `Add` function, my version works just fine by pushing couple of r registers initially.