# data movement error clarification

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm currently solving problem 3.3 from 3rd edition of Computer System: a programmer's perspective and I'm having a hard time understanding what these errors mean...

`movb $0xF, (%ebx)` gives an error because ebx can't be used as address register

`movl %rax, (%rsp)` and 
   `movb %si, 8(%rbp)` gives error saying that theres a mismatch between instruction suffix and register I.D.

`movl %eax, %rdx` gives an error saying that destination operand incorrect size

why can't we use ebx as address register? Is it because its 32-bit register? Would the following line work if it was `movb $0xF, (%rbx)` instead? since rbx is of 64bit register?

for the error regarding mismatch between instruction suffix and register I.D, does this error appear because it should've been `movq %rax, (%rsp)`and `movew %si, 8(%rbp)` instead of `movl %rax, (%rsp)` and `movb %si, 8(%rbp)`?

and lastly, for the error regarding "destination operand incorrect size", is this because the destination register was 64 bit instead of 32? so if the line of code was `movl %eax, %edx` instead, the error wouldn't have occurred?

any enlightenment would be appreciated.

this is for x86-64

Comment: Yes if you're using a 64bit architecture addresses must be 64 bits in length.

Comment: `movb $0xf, (%ebx)` is correct.  You just need an address size override to use it.  Does your assembler perhaps not support this?

Comment: @fuz not sure, but what about `movb $0xf, (%bx)` would this be correct as well if address size is overrided?

Comment: @calebeja9 No.  Address size can only be 32 bit or 64 bit in long mode.

Comment: Is this from CS:APP 3rd edition, "global' version?  It's full of incorrect claims about x86-64 in the practice problems.  [CS:APP example uses idivq with two operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57998998) has some info about the situation with that book, and the clueless people hired by the publisher who made up new problems without understanding x86-64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
movb $0xF, (%ebx) gives an error because ebx can't be used as address register
```

It's true that `ebx` can't be used as an address register (for x86-64), but `rbx` can.  ebx is the lower 32bits of rbx.  The whole point of 64bit code is that addresses can be 64bits, so trying to reference memory by using a 32bit register makes little sense.

```
movl %rax, (%rsp) and movb %si, 8(%rbp) gives error saying that 
theres a mismatch between instruction suffix and register I.D.
```

Yes, because you are using `movl`, the 'l' means long, which (in this context) means 32bits.  However, rax is a 64bit register.  If you want to write 64bits out of rax, you should use `movq`.  If you want to write 32bits, you should use `eax`.

```
movl %eax, %rdx gives an error saying that destination operand incorrect size
```

You are trying to move a 32bit value into a 64bit register.  There are instructions to do this conversion for you (see `cdq` for example), but movl isn't one of them.

Comment: `movb $0xF, (%ebx)` assembles just fine (with a `0x67` address-size prefix), and executes correctly if the address in `ebx` is valid.  The only reason you'd ever use that instead of `movb $0xF, (%rbx)` is if the upper bytes of `%rbx` potentially held garbage, e.g. [in the x32 ABI (ILP32 in long mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI), or if you're a dumb compiler that [always uses address-size prefixes when targeting 32-bit-pointer mode even when addresses are known to be safely zero-extended](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85038).  So `gcc -mx32` could easily emit it.

Answer (score 0):

`movb $0xF, (%ebx)` assembles just fine (with a `0x67` address-size prefix), and executes correctly if the address in `ebx` is valid.

It might be a bug (and e.g. lead to a segfault from truncating a pointer), or sub-optimal, but if your book makes any stronger claim than that (like that it won't assemble) then your book contains an error.

The only reason you'd ever use that instead of `movb $0xF, (%rbx)` is if the upper bytes of `%rbx` potentially held garbage, e.g. [in the x32 ABI (ILP32 in long mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI), or if you're a dumb compiler that [always uses address-size prefixes when targeting 32-bit-pointer mode even when addresses are known to be safely zero-extended](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85038).

32-bit address size is actually useful for the x32 ABI for the more common case where an index register holds high garbage, e.g. `movl $0x12345, (%edi, %esi,4)`.

`gcc -mx32` could easily emit a `movb $0xF, (%ebx)` instruction in real life.    (Note that `-mx32` (32-bit pointers in long mode) is different from `-m32` (i386 ABI))

```
int ext();          // can't inline
void foo(char *p) { 
    ext();          // clobbers arg-passing registers
    *p = 0xf;       // so gcc needs to save the arg for after the call
}
```

Compiles with [`gcc7.3 -mx32 -O3` on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+ext()%3B%0Avoid+foo(char+*p)+%7B+%0A++++ext()%3B%0A++++*p+%3D+0xf%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.339829476248475,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-O3+-mx32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:48.660170523751525,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) into

```
foo(char*):
    pushq   %rbx              # rbx is gcc's first choice of call-preserved reg.
    movq    %rdi, %rbx        # stupid gcc copies the whole 64 bits when only the low 32 are useful
    call    ext()
    movb    $15, (%ebx)       # $15 = $0xF
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```

`mov $edi, %ebx` would have been better; IDK why gcc wants to copy the whole 64-bit register when it's treating pointers as 32-bit values.  The x32 ABI unfortunately never really caught on on x86 so I guess nobody's put in the time to get gcc to generate great code for it.

AArch64 also has an ILP32 ABI to save memory / cache-footprint on pointer data, so maybe gcc will get better at 32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode in general (benefiting x86-64 as well) if any work for AArch64 ILP32 improves the common cross-architecture parts of this.

---

> so if the line of code was movl %eax, %edx instead, the error wouldn't have occurred?

Right, [that would zero-extend EAX into RDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).  If you wanted to *sign*-extend EAX into RDX, use [`movslq %eax, %rdx` (aka Intel-syntax `movsxd`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555094/what-does-cltq-do-in-assembly/45386217#45386217)

(Almost) all x86 instructions require all their operands to be the same size.  (In terms of operand-size; many instructions have a form with an 8-bit or 32-bit immediate that's sign extended to 64-bit or whatever the instruction's operand-size is.  e.g. `add $1, %eax` will use the 3-byte [`add imm8, r/m32` form](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html).)

Exceptions include `shl %cl, %eax`, and movzx/movsx.

In AT&T syntax, the sizes of registers have to match the operand-size suffix, if you use one.  If you don't, the registers imply an operand-size.  e.g. `mov %eax, %edx` is the same as `movl`.

Memory + immediate instructions with no register source or destination need an explicit size: `add $1, (%rdx)` won't assemble because the operand-size is ambiguous, but `add %eax, (%rdx)` is an `addl` (32-bit operand-size).

> `movew  %si, 8(%rbp)`

No, `movw %si, 8(%rbp)` would work though :P  But note that if you've made a traditional stack frame with `push %rbp` / `mov %rsp, %rbp` on function entry, that store to `8(%rbp)` will overwrite the low 16 bits of your return address on the stack.

But there's no requirement in x86-64 code for Windows or Linux that you have `%rbp` pointing there, or holding a valid pointer at all.  It's just a call-preserved register like `%rbx` that you can use for whatever you want as long as you restore the caller's value before returning.