# What is the 64-bit equivalent of the "cltd" instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm looking at Oracle's documentation for x86, and the documentation for `cltd` says:

```
%eax -> %edx:%eax
```

So what I'm asking is, what is the instruction that does this:

```
%rax -> %rdx:%rax
```

I think it's `cqto` or `cqo` but is this correct?

Comment: Misread the question at first. Yes `cqto` (or `cqo`) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Have you tried assembling `cqto`?  As far as I'm concerned, that is indeed correct.

Comment: [My answer on What does cltq do in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45386217) runs down the full details on Intel vs. AT&T syntax for cdq (cltd) / cqo (cqto) and so on, and what they do.  **Yes, `cqto`, aka Intel CQO, sign extends RAX into RDX:RAX.**  Modern GAS probably accepts either mnemonic.