# IA32 Assembly code for type casting from signed/unsigned char to unsigned/signed int

Tags: assembly, x86, type-conversion, att, integer-promotion

This is from Computer Systems, a Programmer's perspective (2nd edition)

In question 3.4, the student is asked to determine the assembly instruction needed to cast from a source data type to a destination that is referred to by a pointer

This answer given at the back of the chapter states that we need to sign extend the source type (left column) to the destination type (middle column).

[image]

There isn't much information to pull a pattern from this question. Is it always the case that the type of extension is determined by the source type and not the destination type, as in this example?

Comment: What language is this? The only HLLs I know that have both `char` and `unsigned char` are C and C++, and this is wrong for those. For _most_ integer types in , `x` is signed and `unsigned x` is unsigned (except possibly when used in bitfield), but for `char` signedness is implementation-dependent which means (as defined in the standard) it can vary but must be documented. This part of C is copied by C++.

Comment: The textbook uses only C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your book.

> When performing a cast that involves both a size change and a change
>   of “signedness” in C, the operation should change the size first. (Section 2.2.6).
>
> -- CSAPP 2e, Practice Problem 3.4

So these two conversions work like this:

```
char --> int --> unsigned int
unsigned char --> unsigned int --> int
```

Comment: In C, there is a size change that happens as a result of the *integer promotion* rules, and then the cast is applied.  So, first `unsigned char --> int` then the cast is applied.  Widening an `unsigned char` to `int` means zero extension in order to represent all the values in the wider `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it always the case that the type of extension is determined by the source type and not the destination type, as in this example?

Yes.

**Casting preserves the *value* represented by the original bits (if possible).**  The rules follow from that, so that's the key concept that lets you think through why everything else is the way it is.

- If it's unsigned, you make it wider by padding with zeroes at the left.
  (zero extension: `movzx`, AT&T `movzbl` / `movzwl` / `movl` (dword to qword on x86-64))
- If it's signed, you make it wider by padding with copies of the sign bit.
  ([2's complement sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Sign_extension)<sup>1</sup>: `movsx`, or AT&T `movsbl` / `movswl` / `movsb/wq`)
- For any value, you make it narrower by simply truncating
  (read the low byte from memory, or the narrower partial register)

Doing anything else wouldn't be value-preserving.  e.g. for narrow unsigned -> wider signed, the wider type can represent every possible value of the narrower type.  And the result must be non-negative so the sign bit must be zero.  **Other than the sign bit, 2's complement and unsigned binary place values are identical.**  So zero-extension works.  e.g. `192` as a `uint8_t` is the same as `192` as an `int`, but with more zero bits to the left in the `int`.

From ISO C11 ([n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), the conversion rules are eminently sensible and match what your textbook is showing:

> ### 6.3 Conversions
>
> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>      is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>      can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>      the new type.60)
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>      implementation-defined signal is raised.

For point 2, note that the "as if by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than MAX_INT" is (for 2's complement) equivalent to simply reinterpreting the bit-pattern as signed.  i.e. **no asm operation is required for casting int to unsigned**, you just `mov` or even better read whatever register or memory the value was already in.

More detail on that: Unsigned types can't represent negative values, so that's one case where it can't be "value preserving" for negative inputs even if they're narrower.  You can think of it as logically sign extending to an equal-width signed type (which can represent the value), then converting to unsigned (just reinterpreting the same bits, i.e. no extra asm instructions after the widening conversion).

---

Footnote 1: x86 uses 2's complement, and so does everything else that's relevant.  C++ is even considering dropping the option for implementations to use sign/magnitude or 1's complement integer.

---

**Also note that the textbook's answer uses a not-encodeable form of `movz/sbl`.**  They're only available with a register destination.  `movzbl %al, %ebx` is fine, `movzbl (%esi), %ebx` is also fine, but `movzbl %al, (%ebx)` is *not* fine.

Also related:

- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx / * https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx
- [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387571/movzx-missing-32-bit-register-to-64-bit-register)
- [What does cltq do in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555094/what-does-cltq-do-in-assembly/45386217#45386217) - equivalent table for Intel vs. AT&T `movsb/w`, and the special case AX->EAX and similar instructions.