# Sign-extending with cltq

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Is the `cltq` its own instruction, or is it an alias for something else? I couldn't find it on the [x86 page](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html). As it does:

```
cltq  # fill high 32 bits with 1 if current (eax) MSB is 1 else 0
# movslq %eax, %rax
```

Are there other 'forms' of it, so that it can work on other byte-sizes or registers or does it only work on the accumulator register? If it's always fixed to that, why would it be so common to fix it to that? My only thought is if the return value is an `int` in C and its common to cast that to a `long`, but this is merely just a random guess.

Comment: My answer on [What does cltq do in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45386217) explains the history of why x86 has redundant short-forms of sign extending within RAX.  (The mnemonic is AT&T syntax for `cdqe`, which you could also have found out with a quick google, or by checking the opcode.)

Comment: @PeterCordes oh I see, it's stored there, thanks for pointing that out: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cbw:cwde:cdqe

Comment: I believe 8086 originally had two such instructions, each with its own opcode: `cbw`, extending `al` into `ax`, and `cwd`, extending `ax` into `dx:ax`.  These would have been useful as precursors to 8-bit and 16-bit `idiv` respectively, when your divisor is only 8/16 bits.  Each begot its own family of 32- and 64-bit versions with appropriate operand size prefixes: `cbw` gave us `cwde` and `cdqe` extending `ax` into itself (`ax->eax, eax->rax`), and `cwd` led to `cdq` and `cqo`, extending `ax` into `dx` (`eax->edx:eax` and `rax->rdx:rax` respectively).

Comment: @PeterCordes by the way: you mention 'checking the opscode' -- what's the quickest way to do that? Usually I'm in `gdb` and it shows the instruction and memory address but not the opcode, such as `0x0000000000400090  ? cltq`.

Comment: `objdump --disassemble` has a reasonable format that shows the machine code bytes along with the disassembly.

Comment: GDB disassembly can show the machine code with `disas /r`, but IIRC that doesn't work with `layout reg` mode.  As Nate says, use `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  (Intel-syntax disassembly will use Intel mnemonics, which is useful if you want to look instructions up in Intel manuals...)

Comment: For future reference, some other correspondences between AT&T and Intel mnemonics are documented [in the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html#i386_002dMnemonics).

Comment: @NateEldredge What does the `c` stand for the in the `cltq`? I'm guessing the `ltq` part is long-to-quad, but what about `c` ?

Comment: I think it means `convert`, that is `cbw` means `convert (signed) byte to (signed) word`.