# Set EDX to 0 or -1 according to an EAX >= 0 condition?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization

I am learning intelx64 assembly (AT&T)

I saw a question to translate from C code to assembly:

```
if (a>=0)
    b=0;
else
    b=-1;
```

where I was given:

```
movl a,%eax
___________
movl %edx, b
```

While I can solve this in 2 lines or more I can't think of something to solve it in 1 line, any help or hint?

Answer (score 4):

[`cdq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cwd:cdq:cqo) copies the sign-bit of EAX into all bits of EDX.
Having its sign bit set is equivalent to EAX being less-than zero.

`-1` is all-bits-set in a 2's complement machine like x86.

Another way to describe `cdq` is sign-extending EAX into EDX:EAX.

[The AT&T mnemonic for it is `cltd`, very easy to confuse with `cltq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45386217/224132), so I recommend just using the Intel mnemonics for those instructions (`cdq` vs. `cdqe`, where the E for "Extend" is a reminder that it's within one register, into RAX.)

---

In general, you can try asking a compiler to see if you can get them to use a single instruction for something, or look at the instructions they generate.

Or use a [superoptimizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoptimization) which is software that brute-force tries possible instruction sequences to find the best / shortest one to produce a given result, for a given set of inputs.  (Only viable for *very* short sequences, like a handful of instructions.)

By hand / by eye, you can see that `mov` doesn't set FLAGS according to the value, so that rules out any instructions like `cmov`.  And there aren't any instructions that branch based on EAX (unlike `loop` for RCX), and you don't want that anyway.  For me, the solution came to mind as soon as I saw it was storing EDX into `b`.  The combination of EAX and EDX, along with needing a `0` or `-1`, reminded me of `cdq`.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't learn thus not allowed to use cdq, aren't there alternatives?

Comment: maybe we can use the fact that value of b is equal to MSB of a repeated?

Comment: @daniel: *maybe we can use the fact that value of b is equal to MSB of a repeated?* Yes, that's exactly what `cdq` does, that's why it's the answer.  I'm pretty sure it's the only single instruction that does that, which is why 8086 included it in the first place (to set up for `idiv`).  The other option would be `mov %eax, %edx` / `sar $31, %edx`.  If you haven't learned it yet, learn it now; that's why I linked the manual when I first mentioned it.

Comment: One way to get compilers to do this is to ask them to sign-extend int to long long, with `-m32 -mregparm=3` (so the arg arrives in EAX, returned in EDX:EAX) https://godbolt.org/z/bPdhqqGdG